# Reducing Linux LVM size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-esxi

this server has an Ubuntu 10.10 LVM volume created out of three "thin provisioning" VMWare ESXi disks of 1.76tb each and one 700Gb "thick provisioning" disk.

Here's the space used according to pvs:

```
root@UBUSRV64:/mnt$ sudo pvs -o+pv_used
  PV         VG             Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  Used
  /dev/sda5  UBUSRV64       lvm2 a-     3,76g 40,00m   3,72g
  /dev/sdb1  VOLGROUP-DATOS lvm2 a-   700,00g     0  700,00g
  /dev/sdc1  VOLGROUP-DATOS lvm2 a-     1,76t     0    1,76t
  /dev/sdd1  VOLGROUP-DATOS lvm2 a-     1,76t     0    1,76t
  /dev/sde1  VOLGROUP-DATOS lvm2 a-     1,76t     0    1,76t
```

Now, using `df -h`:

```
root@UBUSRV64:/mnt$ df -h
S.ficheros            TamaÃ±o Usado  Disp Uso% Montado en
/dev/mapper/UBUSRV64-root
                      3,5G  3,3G     0 100% /
none                  5,9G  216K  5,9G   1% /dev
none                  5,9G     0  5,9G   0% /dev/shm
none                  5,9G  500K  5,9G   1% /var/run
none                  5,9G     0  5,9G   0% /var/lock
none                  5,9G     0  5,9G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1             228M   51M  166M  24% /boot
/dev/mapper/VOLGROUP--DATOS-datos
                      5,9T  2,2T  3,5T  39% /mnt/datos
```

As you can see, there are only 2.2Tb used.

I would like to reduce the size of LVM disk, to let me shrink the VMWare disks and eventually create several smaller Thick provisioned disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to shrink the filesystem first. If and how that is possible depends on the filesystem used.

Then you can `lvreduce` the logical volume and `vgreduce` the volume group.

Be aware that any such operation is potentially dangerous and may lead to loss of data. It would be much safer to add new disk with new filesystem, copy data and remove the old/unused ones.

Comment: You are right. I marked this as the correct answer, though I will not reduce the filesystem, because I convinced the owner to move all the files except those disks from the datastore, leaving only the thin provisioning disks there.